# How to make FSI work under NET5 and make stupid stackoverflow message "Title cannot contain ..." shut up?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, .net-5

I am migrating a fairly small F# project from Net Framework to NET5. The migration was very easy and everything works including the tests.

However, when I run some scripts I am now getting the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.0.0 for F# 5.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> 
[Loading C:\Users\kkkma\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\28772--091a5e4a-2a27-4d4d-9891-2b58055c5317\Project.fsproj.fsx
 Loading C:\GitHub\Berreman\Berreman\Analytics\Examples\References.fsx]
namespace FSI_0002.Project

namespace FSI_0002

[Loading C:\Users\kkkma\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\28772--091a5e4a-2a27-4d4d-9891-2b58055c5317\Project.fsproj.fsx]
namespace FSI_0003.Project

Binding session to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.dll'...
Binding session to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'...
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ICloneable' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at Berreman.MathNetNumericsMath.complexDiagonalMatrix(Int32 n, Complex e)
   at Berreman.Geometry.complexIdentityMatrix(Int32 n) in C:\GitHub\Berreman\Berreman\Berreman\Geometry.fs:line 17
   at Berreman.Geometry.ComplexMatrix3x3.get_identity() in C:\GitHub\Berreman\Berreman\Berreman\Geometry.fs:line 307
   at Berreman.MaterialProperties.Eps.fromRefractionIndex(RefractionIndex _arg1) in C:\GitHub\Berreman\Berreman\Berreman\MaterialProperties.fs:line 70
   at FSI_0004.opticalProperties(RefractionIndex refractionIndex) in C:\GitHub\Berreman\Berreman\Analytics\Examples\Glass_01.fsx:line 51
   at FSI_0004.getGlassInfo(Boolean useThickPlate, RefractionIndexThickness nh1, FSharpOption`1 nh2Opt, IncidentLightInfo light) in C:\GitHub\Berreman\Berreman\Analytics\Examples\Glass_01.fsx:line 61
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0004>.$FSI_0004.main@() in C:\GitHub\Berreman\Berreman\Analytics\Examples\Glass_01.fsx:line 98
Stopped due to error
>
```

When I examine `Project.fsproj.resolvedReferences.paths` from `C:\Users\kkkma\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\28772--091a5e4a-2a27-4d4d-9891-2b58055c5317` (and that's the folder created by FSI when I run the script) I see that it starts from `C:\Users\kkkma\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netframework.referenceassemblies.net48\1.0.0\build\.NETFramework\v4.8\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll` and it also has some other Net Framework resolved references. Which makes me believe that FSI somehow "decides" to use Net Framework instead of NET 5.

The file `fsi.runtimeconfig.json` contains correct information:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to force FSI pick up NET 5 instead of Net Framework?

Comment: .NET 5 fsi uses `dotnet fsi` to execute scripts. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: I am using CTRL+A, then ALT+ENTER in Visual Studio and it runs FSI. This is how it always worked. The output is in the question above.

Comment: Gotcha, yes. VS uses .NET Framework for FSI because VS is a .NET Framework exe itself. You will need to execute your scripts separately against `dotnet fsi`.

Comment: @PhillipCarter Are you saying that it is impossible to run the scripts from inside VS and they have to be run manually via `dotnet fsi`? If this is the case, then it kills the purpose. or do you have an example of how to coerce VS to run `dotnet fsi` instead of just `fsi`? Thanks.

Comment: Currently they need to be run with `dotnet fsi` and outside of VS. A future version of VS may offer a way to run scripts that depend on .NET 5 from within the IDE.

Comment: @PhillipCarter Well that's a shame. I had similar problem when trying to run in VS:

#r "nuget: FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq"

and got 

"error NU1202: Package FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq 3.0.2 is not compatible with net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8). Package FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq 3.0.2 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)"

FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq targets only netstandard and I imagine this kind of packages will be more popular over time.

Comment: @PhillipCarter , @lucask I am also using Rider nightly builds and as of today there is an option to switch FSI version from `VS 2019` to `.NET Core SDK 5.0.100`. When it runs, I can see the following command at the top: `"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" fsi --optimize+ --quiet --fsi-server:0 --readline- --shadowcopyreferences- --langversion:preview --fsi-server-output-codepage:65001 --fsi-server-input-codepage:65001`, which seems fine, except that it does not properly work yet. Anyway, I guess that is coming and Rider might be faster to make it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 2019 [version 16.9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes), you can enable an option to use `dotnet fsi` to run interactive F# scripts.  This works with .NET 5 code.

This is set via Tools > Options > F# Tools > F# Interactive > Use .NET Core Scripting.

Full details and instructions can be found at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/f-and-f-tools-update-for-visual-studio-16-9/