# F# interactive fails to reference nuget package with no .NET framework compatibility

Tags: f#, nuget, f#-interactive

In Visual Studio 2019 16.8.2 I am trying to reference a nuget package in the embedded F# interactive session

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.0.0 for F# 5.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

#r @"nuget: EventStore.Client.Grpc.ProjectionManagement,20.6.1"
```

The package does not support .NET Framework (.NET Core only) so I get the following error

```
error NU1202: Package EventStore.Client.Grpc.ProjectionManagement 20.6.1 is not compatible with net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8).
```

I tried to change the fsi parameters adding --noframework (and resetting F# interactive), with no luck.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, that package actually provides a netstandard lib too, but for some reason fsi is trying to use the .Net Core lib. As a temporary workaround, you can directly reference the netstandard lib on disk: `#r @"<homedir>\.nuget\packages\eventstore.client.grpc.projectionmanagement\20.6.1\lib\netstandard2.1\EventStore.Client.ProjectionManagement.dll"`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804440/how-to-make-fsi-work-under-net5-and-make-stupid-stackoverflow-message-title-can) for an updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Visual Studio's F# Interactive window can only run the .NET Framework version of FSI. In order to use non-Framework compatible packages in FSI you need to either use the command line version of FSI or directly reference the netstandard version of the nuget package.

Command Line Version:

```
PS> dotnet fsi

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.0.0 for F# 5.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> #r @"nuget: EventStore.Client.Grpc.ProjectionManagement,20.6.1";;
```

Visual Studio Integrated FSI Version:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.0.0 for F# 5.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> #r @"<homedir>\.nuget\packages\eventstore.client.grpc.projectionmanagement\20.6.1\lib\netstandard2.1\EventStore.Client.ProjectionManagement.dll";;
```